# To obtain date value from the SQL Server database using linq in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I try to get `Last_Login_Date` value with data type `DateTime` from SQL Server using linq command in C# but I have no idea what to put after the

```
WHERE m.Last_Login_Date==???????
```

and this action is taken when a user clicked login. So I must get the specific user id with the email address.

Please send solution if possible. Thank you for giving contribution.

```
var lastLoginDate = from m in db.Members
                    where m.Last_Login_Date ==;
```

Comment: You see you are wrong at core business itself. you never get User Id from `Last_Login_Date`, u get `Last_Login_Date` from the user id.

Comment: Where is supposed to be used to get an entity from db instead of All records. Where x.id == 12345 select x.Last_login_date

Comment: Hi @HowToGame, welcome to SO. There is not enough information. What does the table `Members` look like? What's the name of the column that contains the user id? What's the name of the column that contains the password?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided information about the schema, so I'll make up column names to illustrate. Assuming column `EmailAddress` and Db Context class `DbClassName`, here is a sample function:

```
private DateTime? GetLastLoginDate(string emailAddress)
{        
    using(var db = new DbClassName())
    {        
        //Find the user
        var user = db.Members.FirstOrDefault(m => m.EmailAddress == emailAddress);
        return user?.Last_Login_Date;
    }
}
```

This method will take in an email address (which would come from the login page) and look up the user by email address. If found, it will return the last login date, otherwise it will return `null`.

Note that you don't need the password to look up the user, unless more than one account is allowed to have the same email address (this is usually not the case).

Please keep in mind this is an overly simplistic example. You should consider things like string sanitation and case sensitivity, but this should get you going.